# Can a flutter web app be deployed on hostinger?

Tags: flutter, dart

Wanted to know if a flutter web app can be deployed to shared hosting like hostinger.com or not. I tried to do it by following these [steps](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/160/how-to-deploy-flutter-web-on-cpanel-shared-hosting/) but did not work.
All I am getting is a blank page but the flutter fav icon is being displayed.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, just compile the app locally and upload it via ftp or the file manager as in the example you show. The only extra step you are missing is that you must set up a Node App so that your webapp runs on it, since flutter web compiles to javaScrypt. CPannel brings the option for this, but I don't know if all hosting providers enable it. I have done it successfully on Namecheap shared hosting.[Setup Node App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lT5F.jpg)